# As a mastermind, is there a maximum of cops possible to convert?

Tags: payday-2

> JOKER
>
> You can convert a non-special enemy to fight on your side. The enemy
>   must have surrendered in order for you to convert it.

Thanks to this wonderful skill, you can turn other cops.  But last time I played, after I turned one of the cops, I couldn't turn another one.  The cop surrendered but after that, while trying to turn him, I received a "Your persuasion capacities have been resisted" message...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the perk's description you may only have 1 turned companion to fight for you.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you may only have 1 **at a time.**

Comment: @SpellingD It might be worth noting that this answer was valid at the patch released around the time of the answer. It also might be worth noting that the answer comes from the description provided by the JOKER perk, NOT the DOMINATOR perk (which is increased/nerfed in between patches).